# Will methods in lambda only be evaluated when the lambda is executed?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Can we be sure that methods being called in a java lambda are *only* being called when the lambda itself is executed, and *never* in advance?

If you take a look at my code:

```java
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("my result");
Supplier<String> mySupplier = () -> "result: " + myStringBuilder.toString();
myStringBuilder.append(", after appending.");
System.out.println(mySupplied.get());
```

Can we be 100% certain that the result will always be:

> result: my result, after appending

And *never* just

> result: my result

Comment: Is there a reason you think the result of the lambda will be pre-computed? And that it will be pre-computed *only once*?

Comment: Yes. It's evaluated lazily.

Comment: Lambdas are put in a method of an interface instantiation, and are never executed on beforehand.

Comment: oh the surprise people would have if this would be otherwise... it's like a method call, would you like some of them to be called without you doing that explicitly? I doubt it

Comment: That’s the difference to, e.g. `Supplier<String> mySupplier = ("result: " + myStringBuilder)::toString;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following snappet:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> expensiveMethod();  // Runnable not called
firstMethodCall();                            // Runnable not called
secondMethodCall();                           // Runnable not called
runnable.run();                               // HERE IT COMES, Runnable IS called
```

The lambda expression is nothing else than the implementation of an anonymous class with one method (this secures [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation).

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     void run() {
         expensiveMethod();
     }
};

// runnable's method is not executed since the method run is not called
// the runnable.run() invokes the expensiveMethod()
```

The Java 8 specification [15.27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) explains that the expression is called when the *appropriate method of the functional interface is invoked*:

> Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface (§9.8). Lambda expression evaluation does not cause the execution of the expression's body; instead, this may occur at a later time when an appropriate method of the functional interface is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

> Lambda expression evaluation does not cause the execution of the expression's body; instead, this may occur at a later time when an appropriate method of the functional interface is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The lambda code only executes when called not when the containing line is executed.

Comment: Could you add a source to you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is like implementation code of an interface and just like an interface implementation, it will only be executed when you call it.

Comment: Could you add a source to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Lamba is an implementation of a **Functional Interface**. Its content will be changed / computed at the time of its call.

So, yes, you can 100% be sure about your assumption :)